# Sort ArrayList in a better way

Tags: java, array, sorting

I have a list of categories (in this example I used `String` but in my project I have a model) which must be sorted like this:

- on top we should have 2 categories which have a fixed position in the list (in this example (C, F))
- at the bottom of the list we should have 3 categories which have a fixed position in the list (in this example (R, M, P))
- in the middle of the list we should have the rest of the elements sorted alphabetically

I want to know if there is a better solution than I used, for sorting the list this way. I do not want to use `HashMap`, so if anyone could find a better solution for sorting the `ArrayList`, I would highly appreciate it.

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add("A");
    categories.add("B");
    categories.add("C");
    categories.add("D");
    categories.add("E");
    categories.add("F");
    categories.add("G");
    categories.add("H");
    categories.add("I");
    categories.add("J");
    categories.add("K");
    categories.add("L");
    categories.add("M");
    categories.add("N");
    categories.add("O");
    categories.add("P");
    categories.add("Q");
    categories.add("R");

    sortCategories(categories);
```

The `sortCategories()` method is:

```
public void sortCategories(List<String> categories) {
    List<String> topCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> bottomCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String category : categories) {
        if (category.equals("C")) {
            topCategories.add(category);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (String category : categories) {
        if (category.equals("F")) {
            topCategories.add(category);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (String category : categories) {
        if (category.equals("R")) {
            bottomCategories.add(category);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (String category : categories) {
        if (category.equals("M")) {
            bottomCategories.add(category);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (String category : categories) {
        if (category.equals("P")) {
            bottomCategories.add(category);
            break;
        }
    }

    categories.removeAll(topCategories);
    categories.removeAll(bottomCategories);

    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });

    categories.addAll(0, topCategories);
    categories.addAll(categories.size(), bottomCategories);
}
```

And the output is:

> ```
> Category NAME C
> Category NAME F
> Category NAME A
> Category NAME B
> Category NAME D
> Category NAME E
> Category NAME G
> Category NAME H
> Category NAME I
> Category NAME J
> Category NAME K
> Category NAME L
> Category NAME N
> Category NAME O
> Category NAME Q
> Category NAME R
> Category NAME M
> Category NAME P
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not hard-code category values into the code, but rather make them configurable, so that your code may be re-used with other top/bottom category values. Since you have a specific sorting algorithm, it is probably best to create a custom comparator, which encapsulates all of the sorting logic. That comparator would be initialized with the values allowed for top/bottom categories, and would do the sorting, taking these values into account.

Using the comparator should be as simple as:

```
    List<String> allCategories = Arrays.asList(
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
            "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
            "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"
            );
    List<String> topCategories = Arrays.asList("C", "F");
    List<String> bottomCategories = Arrays.asList("M", "P", "R");
    Collections.sort(allCategories, new CategoryComparator(topCategories, bottomCategories));
```

There are many ways to implement such a comparator.The main idea is to extend the comparison logic: in addition to comparing values, you also compare their belonging to a particular category, and adjust the score consequently. As a result, values belonging to the top category should be put on top, and if two values belong to the same category, they should be compared according to their natural order.

```
public class CategoryComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static final int POSITIVE_SCORE = +1;
    private static final int NEGATIVE_SCORE = -1;
    private static final int TOP_SCORE_ADJUSTMENT = -2;
    private static final int BOTTOM_SCORE_ADJUSTMENT = +2;

    private Set<String> topCategories;
    private Set<String> bottomCategories;

    public CategoryComparator(Collection<String> topCategories, Collection<String> bottomCategories) {
        this.topCategories = new HashSet<>(topCategories);
        this.bottomCategories = new HashSet<>(bottomCategories);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return normalizeScore(o1.compareTo(o2)) + ajustScoreForCategory(o1) - ajustScoreForCategory(o2);
    }

    private int normalizeScore(int score) {
        if (score < 0) {
            return NEGATIVE_SCORE;
        }
        if (score > 0) {
            return POSITIVE_SCORE;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int ajustScoreForCategory(String value) {
        int scoreAdjustment = 0;
        if (topCategories.contains(value)) {
            scoreAdjustment += TOP_SCORE_ADJUSTMENT;
        }
        if (bottomCategories.contains(value)) {
            scoreAdjustment += BOTTOM_SCORE_ADJUSTMENT;
        }
        return scoreAdjustment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two major flaws:

**1) It has bad runtime behaviour:**

First looking up the special cases, treat them remove them. treat the rest.
This are too many iterations over the source material

**2) It is unneccessary complex:**

From (1)

**Alternatively:**

It depends on how much effort you want to put in, otherwise, this will do (for your simple case):

**JAVA 8**:

```
private List<String> sortCategories(List<String> allCategories) {
    String[] topCategories=new String[2];
    String[] bottomCategories=new String[3];
    SortedSet<String> rest = new TreeSet<>();
    List <String> result=new ArrayList<>();
    allCategories.stream().forEach(
            x->{
                switch(x){
                    case "C":
                        topCategories[0]=x;
                        break;
                    case "F":
                        topCategories[1]=x;
                        break;
                    case "M":
                        bottomCategories[0]=x;
                        break;
                    case "P":
                        bottomCategories[1]=x;
                        break;
                    case "R":
                        bottomCategories[2]=x;
                        break;
                    default:
                        rest.add(x);
                }
            }
    );
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(topCategories));
    result.addAll(rest);
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(bottomCategories));
    return result;
}
```

**Pro:**

- Does, what it should.
- Is simple.
- Easy to understand.
- Easy to maintain.
- Easy to extend.
- Runs linear through your source data set

**Contra:**

- Hard codes the positions of the *top* / *bottom* categories
- Uses a "nasty" switch

So, I would prefer this approach as a first shot. And if you have to later add more complexity: refactor it!

But perhaps *YAGNI* comes, and you have never to revisit this "ugly" code.
There is no overcomplex *Abstraction* or *Overengineering*  invested.

Of course, if you are dealing with `objects` instead of `Strings` you have to take care, that they are *comparable* to each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting approach. But unfortunately I work on Android (I forgot to mention, sorry) and it doesn't support Java 8. But it's good to know :) Thanks again.